How to publish messages to a topic in Solace broker using AMQP
We have a Quarkus app that uses the smallrye-amqp connector. I have the following code for publishing messages to a topic.
@ApplicationScoped
public class InsightLifecycleObserver {

    public static final String INSIGHTS_DELETED_TOPIC = "insightscentral/insight/deleted";

    @Inject
    @Channel(INSIGHTS_DELETED_TOPIC)
    @OnOverflow(value = Strategy.NONE)
    Emitter<byte[]> insightsEmitter;
    void onInsightRemoved(@Observes(during = AFTER_SUCCESS) InsightDeletedEvent event) {


        final var tenantId = tenantResolver.getTenantId();
        try {
          var insightLifeCycleEvent = convertToLifeCycleEvent(event);
          var eventEnvelope =
              EventEnvelope.builder()
                  .withId(UUID.randomUUID())
                  .withData(
                      PojoCloudEventData.wrap(insightLifeCycleEvent, objectMapper::writeValueAsBytes))
                  .build();

          // send the event to the Insights topic
          insightsEmitter
              .send(eventEnvelope.serialize())
              .whenComplete(
                  (result, throwable) -> {

                    if (throwable != null) {
                      LOGGER.error("Failed to emit InsightDeleted event", throwable);
                      metricsService.incrementErrorMessageCounter(
                          MessageType.INSIGHT_DELETED_EVENT, tenantId);
                    } else {
                      LOGGER.debug(
                          "Published InsightDeleted event for insight with id: {} and sri: {}",
                          event.insight().id(),
                          event.insight().sri());
                      metricsService.incrementMessageCounter(
                          MessageType.INSIGHT_DELETED_EVENT, tenantId);
                    }
                  });
        } catch (Exception e) {
          LOGGER.error("Failed to publish InsightDeleted event", e);
          metricsService.incrementErrorMessageCounter(MessageType.INSIGHT_DELETED_EVENT, tenantId);
        }
    }

when calling this hook I get the following exception:
io.vertx.core.impl.NoStackTraceThrowable: message rejected (REJECTED): Error{condition=amqp:not-allowed, description='SMF AD ack response error', info={solace.response_code=400, solace.response_text=Queue Not Found}}

What am I doing wrong?

The text response from Solace says, "Queue Not Found," which indicates the queue you're attempting to send the message to doesn't exist or perhaps you don't have permission to send a message to it. Have you investigated these possibilities?

it doesn't exist because I want to publish to a topic not a queue. The idea that I want to publish to a topic so then consumers can create their own subscribing queues.

A client specifies that messages are to be published to a topic by formatting the destination as follows:
topic://topic-string

docs: Solace AMQP ref
thanks to Ozan Günalp for pointing this out here

Instead of the AMQP connector you can use the Solace Quarkus extensions, which provides managed client and messaging connector for Solace PubSub : https://solacelabs.github.io/solace-quarkus/
